# Event Organiser breaks the theme

Tags: themes, css, plugin-event-organiser

I installed a plugin called Events organiser and somehow it breakes the theme when viewing an event page. Can someone help me out as I´m struggling with this and can´t find the mistake.

http://throwholics.com/events/event/indoor-meeting-weltklasse-in-karlsruhe/

Thank you so much.

Comment: Find and correct the last four items listed here: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthrowholics.com%2Fevents%2Fevent%2Findoor-meeting-weltklasse-in-karlsruhe%2F to start.

Comment: done, but still messy

Comment: See [Editing the templates in Event Organiser](http://wp-event-organiser.com/documentation/editing-the-templates/)

Answer (score 1):

Your events page has:

```
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <article id="post-4765" class="post-4765 event type-event status-publish hentry">
            <header class="entry-header">
```

Your home page has:

```
<div class="container_6">
    <div id="main" class="site-main clearfix">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area grid_4">
             <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                 <article id="post-4684" class="post-4684 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-discus tag-robert-harting">
                      <header class="entry-header">
```

To get consistent formatting you need consistent markup. You need to get those into alignment.

I think it is probably a straight HTML question at this point which makes it off-topic. How much of that code is generated by the plugin?

Comment: +1 The plug-in provides default templates which may not work with the theme being used. You should move the templates to your theme, and [edit them there](http://wp-event-organiser.com/documentation/editing-the-templates/). Following an existing theme template (typically `single.php` is recommended).